# Bootstrap showing and collapsing table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so i am writing a program that uses php to collect data from a database and with that data I am creating HTML Strings as shown below.

I am then echoing this data in my HTML file and using bootstrap to create the table, and the table comes out perfectly, but I am looking to be able to have the user that is using my website be able to click on a row and more detailed data about the row they clicked on comes down. The code I wrote to try and accomplish this looks like so:

```
$htmlStr .= '<tr data-toggle="myCollapse" data-target="#details" class="accordion-toggle">';
$htmlStr .= '<td>' some data '</td>';
$htmlStr .= '<td class="text-center">' . number_format(more data) . '</td>';
$htmlStr .= '<td class="text-right">' . round(percentage of certain data) . '%</td>';
$htmlStr .= '</tr>';

$more = FunctionForDetails(details looking for);
$htmlStr .= $more;
```

where FunctionForDetails() returns:

```
$htmlStr .= '<tr id="details" class="myCollapse">';
$htmlStr .= '<td class="text-center"><div>' . detailed data . '</div></td>';
$htmlStr .= '<td class="text-center"><div>' . more . '</div></td>';
$htmlStr .= '<td class="text-center"><div>' . more . '%</div></td>';
$htmlStr .= '</tr>';
```

My table comes out just fine with all the rows, but when I click a row, nothing happens. I want more detailed data about the row they clicked to drop down with more rows, and then go away when they click it again. I also wrote some css and jQuery to go along with it but it still does not work. And yes I am linking the bootstrap libraries and jquery library to my HTML. Any ideas or helpful tips would be wonderful, thank you!

CSS Code:

```
table .myCollapse {
   display: none;
}
table .myCollapse.in {
  display: table-row; !important
}
```

jQuery Code:

`$(".myCollapse").click(function() {
    if($('#versions').hasClass('in')){
        $('#versions').removeClass('in');
    }
    else{
        $('#versions').addClass('in');
    }
});`

Comment: I'm convinced it has to do with my jQuery code or the way I'm inputting it into my html file, because the css code is working but nothing happens when I click, but it could also be my php code

Comment: I'm not seeing the element jQuery('#versions') anywhere in your code sample.  Are you sure you're using the correct selector?  Have you tested to see if your jQuery code is actually being triggered by your conditional statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "in" class doesn't work with !important being after the semicolon.
So try doing this and I think you'll notice some changes at least:

```
table .myCollapse.in {
  display: table-row !important;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too thank you, but nothing is still happening unfortunately

Comment: Can you put in it jsfiddle so i can try few things on it and give you a sure answer?

Comment: Also , can you specify which tag is the one having "versions" as its id? I think you should use it this way: `if($(".myCollapse").hasClass("in"))` , and change all the #versions by .myCollapse in the jquery code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x7wfpnzk/  here is the demo you can look at it an dsee if theres anything you can do

Comment: You need to re-add your external resources for your fiddle in the correct order, and you forgot to include the jQuery core code in addition to the jQuery UI code.  Correct order: jQuery, jQuery UI, then Bootstrap.  Do you have the jQuery core code included on your website?  Your jQuery event will not function without it, which could be your problem

Comment: When i make the jsfiddle use jquery onload from the left sidebar, and change the .rowCollapse with .accordion-toggle , it worked just fine.. check is out, i updated it in jsfiddle

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it but I forgot to include the jQuery core code, thanks for that, now the clicking is working I just have some other small bugs I'm working out now, go ahead and pu tit in the answer if you want to and I'll check it! Thank you

Comment: What are the other bugs?